# Yii - complex queries using createCommand() & IF()

Tags: mysql, database, yii, frameworks, query-builder

I am trying to use the Yii 'queryBuilder' to build a complex SQL query - the existing query looks like the following:

```
    $cmd->select('SUM(redeemedCodes.school_points) AS reportingTotalPoints, redeemedCodes.date_redeemed, redeemedCodes.inactive, redeemedCodes.subject_id);
    $cmd->from('redeemed_codes redeemedCodes');
```

Can anyone explain how amend the SELECT to include an IF element as follows:
IF(orderProduct.subject_message_link = 1 AND orderProduct.message != '', CONCAT(subject.subject_name, ' ', orderProduct.message), subject.subject_name) AS reportingSubjectName')

Is this even possible using the createCommand() in Yii?

I'm trying to build a query similar to this below:

```
SELECT redeemedCodes.user_id AS user_id, SUM(redeemedCodes.school_points) AS reportingTotalPoints, 
IF(orderProduct.subject_message_link = 1 AND orderProduct.message != '', CONCAT(subject.subject_name, ' ', orderProduct.message), subject.subject_name) AS reportingSubjectName 
FROM `redeemed_codes` `redeemedCodes`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Tested:

I think CDbExpression might be handy.

```
$exp = new CDbExpression("IF(orderProduct.subject_message_link = 1 AND orderProduct.message != '', CONCAT(subject.subject_name, ' ', orderProduct.message), subject.subject_name)");
```

and use the $exp wherever you need to put the string. e.g.

```
$sql = "Select *, " . $exp . " as ReportingSubjectName FROM ....";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT redeemedCodes.user_id AS user_id, SUM(redeemedCodes.school_points) AS reportingTotalPoints,         redeemedCodes.date_redeemed, redeemedCodes.inactive, redeemedCodes.subject_id, IF(orderProduct.subject_message_link = 1 AND orderProduct.message != '', CONCAT(subject.subject_name, ' ', orderProduct.message), subject.subject_name) AS reportingSubjectName FROM `redeemed_codes` `redeemedCodes`";

$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to the design on the particular module I need to use the createCommand() as it uses mergeWith() functionality further on in the code so your method won't work, but thanks for effort